# Как переопределить метод в методе с помощью лямбда выражения?

Tags: java, swing, методы, лямбда-выражение

Ситуация следующая: делаю для свинга метод для отображения произвольных схем с помощью `Graphics2D`. Проблема в том, что нужно в методе сделать переопределение метода `painComponent(Graphics G)`.
Переопределенный метод в виде лямбды должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics G){ 
    Graphics g2d = new Graphics2D(); 
    g2d.fillOval(...); 
    g2d.dispose(); 
    // ну и небольшое продолжение снизу
}
```

Как в итоге переопределить данный метод с помощью лямбды, или же есть иной путь?

Comment: `иной путь` для решения какой проблемы? Что значит `переопределить метод с помощью лямбды`?

Comment: Лямбой можно задать тело метода, определенного в функциональном интерфейсе, а у вас подобный не наблюдается.

Comment: @FunctionalInterface в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сделать несколько лямбд-выражений вот так:

```
private Consumer cons = 
    (g) -> {
        Graphics g2d = new Graphics2D(); 
        g2d.fillOval(...); 
        g2d.dispose();
        ....
    }
```

а потом, например, сделать в методе блок switch с выбором разных `Consumer` в зависимости от условия:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
    switch (//нужное вам условие) {
        case //условие 1: 
            cons.accept(g);
            break;
        //далее...
    }
}
```

Либо воспользуйтесь паттерном Фабрика.

Comment: лямбда для удобства. Я просто хочу реализовать переопределение Graphics2D так, чтобы при нажатии на различные кнопки оно переопределялось по разному. И не хочу для этого создавать отдельные классы. В любом случае спасибо за ответ

Comment: @AlexF вы хотите переопределить Graphics2D, чтобы при нажатие на разные кнопки срабатывали разные методы? Воспользуйтесь паттерном фабрика. Или сделайте несколько Consumer и сделайте их вызов в paintComponent в блоке switch.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!